# How to test client certificate

Tags: salesforce, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, authentication, mod-ssl

I'm building a web service to allow salesforce to call to it, the two way SSL is used for security, and salesforce has provided its client certificate: sfdc-client.cert.

In order to test whether salesforce client certificate work or not, I have setup a very simple web on MAC apache and enable SSL and client authentication on ssl config file /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf as below (use self-signed):

```
SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/sfdc-client.cert"
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth  10
```

The first browsing by Chrome, I got "SSL Connection Error", I supposed it's correct in this case.

Then, I have tried to import sfdc-client.cert to key chain access, but it does not work at all because it just supports p12/pfx format.

I also tried to use CURL:

```
curl https://test.com --cert-type der --cert sfdc-client.cert
```

but got the error:

```
curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

I'm totally newbie on this stuff, does anyone know how to test client certificate to make sure it works as above?

Answer (score -1):

First you need to have both the client's certificate and certificate private key to be able to test 2-way SSL authentication.

To test with web browser, follow instructions here: [Is there a way to test 2 way ssl through browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486200/is-there-a-way-to-test-2-way-ssl-through-browser)